# Input on change event not working with Farbtastic color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Farbtastic color picker that customized with a theme that I am using. But I am facing an issue that input on change event not working. Here is my code:

```
 <div class="color-picker">
    <div class="input-group pull-right">
         <div class="form-group dropdown">
             <input type="text" name="color" id="project-color-input" class="color-picker__value" value="{{$project->color}}" placeholder="Color" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
              <div class="color-picker__value"></div>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <div class="color-picker__target"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my JS code

```
$('#project-color-input').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Problem is change event is working when I am directly changing input value, But not working when the value is changing with color picker.

[image]

Maybe I am doing something wrong because I am new to JS. Help me to understand this issue.

Comment: I think without a demo we will just assumes .. it will be better if you have a demo

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Hi, actually this is working with a theme installed, so I can't prepare a demo.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but finally come with this answer .. hope it help

Comment: Awesome @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I find so far is to use the `picker` click event to get the change instead of input change event

```
$('.color-picker__target').on('click' , function(){
   console.log($('#project-color-input').val());
})
```